# Moving a ball on screen - cororna

Tags: lua, touch, coronasdk, move, phase

I made two invisible rectangles on the screen. one on the left side and one on the right side. I have a ball in the middle and I want it to move left or right when I touch them. It works. The problem: I want that if I press one of them and after thet I press the other (While the first still pressed) it will move the othe side but that not happed. for example: I press the right rectangle (The ball moves right) and while it pressed I press the left rectangle, but the ball still goes to the left.

code:

```
function moveLeft( e )
    if (circle.x>_W*0.031 ) then
    if (e.phase=="began") then
    circle:setLinearVelocity( -800*v_circle, 0 )
    end
    if (e.phase=="ended") then
    circle:setLinearVelocity( 0, 0 )
    end 
    if (e.x>_W*0.44) then
    circle:setLinearVelocity( 0, 0 )
    end
end
end

function moveRight( e )
    if (circle.x<_W*0.969) then
    if (e.phase=="began") then
    circle:setLinearVelocity( 800*v_circle, 0 )
    end
    if (e.phase=="ended") then
    circle:setLinearVelocity( 0, 0 )
    end 
    if (e.x<_W*0.556) then
    circle:setLinearVelocity( 0, 0 )
    end
    end
end

    clickLeft = display.newRect( _W*0.212, _H/2, _W*0.7, _H*1.2 )
    clickRight = display.newRect( _W*0.78, _H/2, _W*0.7, _H*1.2 )
    clickLeft.isVisible = false
    clickRight.isVisible = false
    clickLeft:addEventListener( "touch", moveLeft )
    clickRight:addEventListener( "touch", moveRight )
```

I have found more - I have put this code in moveLeft function: (Between ****)

```
function moveLeft( e )
    if (circle.x>_W*0.031 ) then
    if (e.phase=="began") then
    circle:setLinearVelocity( -800*v_circle, 0 )
    **** txt = display.newText("@@@@@@@", _W/2, _H*0.57, "Wekar" , 115 ) ****
    end
    if (e.phase=="ended") then
    circle:setLinearVelocity( 0, 0 )
    end 
    if (e.x>_W*0.44) then
    circle:setLinearVelocity( 0, 0 )
    end
end
end
```

And if I press the right rectangle and after that I press the left (While the first still pressed) it doesn't show nothing.
Namely, in this situation it doesn't even get into the moveLefr function.
please someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to explicitly enable multitouch events in Corona to get this to work.
You enable it by calling:

```
system.activate( "multitouch" )
```

See the [system.activate() documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/system/activate.html#overview) for an example.